# YugabyteDB working under unreliable internet connection?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am interested in Yugabyte’s ability to be geo-distributed. However, I am wondering if the protocol between the different nodes can tolerate DIL conditions (see: [Disconnected, Intermittent and Limited (DIL) [DIDO Wiki]](https://www.omgwiki.org/dido/doku.php?id=dido:public:ra:xapend:xapend.a_glossary:d:dil) ) where the network is not reliable. Are there timeouts? Can they change? Are there protocols/defaults for collisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where the network is not reliable

YugabyteDB and its geo-distribution and replication are created to be able to unexpected issues.

However, it is not a good idea to explicitly create a situation where the connection is not stable, that is simply not what it is created for.

> Are there timeouts? Can they change?

[See yb-master configuration reference | YugabyteDB Docs](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/reference/configuration/yb-master/#raft-flags).

> Are there protocols/defaults for collisions?

The default protocol for collisions is last write wins: [xCluster replication | YugabyteDB Docs](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/architecture/docdb-replication/async-replication/)